# IHostedService - background task locks app

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to run task in different thread which will synchornize data, but it locks whole server (asp net core). i have no idea where i did something wrong.
I tried with tasks, and then with thread, but it always lock my app.

```
 public interface IScopedProcessingService
    {
        Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }

    public class ScopedProcessingService : IScopedProcessingService
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ISynchronizationBackgroundService _syncService;

        public ScopedProcessingService(ISynchronizationBackgroundService syncService)
        {
            _syncService= syncService;
        }

        public Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    _syncService.Synchronize();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"SYNCHRONIZATION ERROR {ex.Message} {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

and the consumer

```
public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedProcessingService =
                    scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

                scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
            }
        });
        t.Start();
        return Task.CompletedTask;

       
    }
}
```

and in the end registration:

```
    services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
    services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, ScopedProcessingService>();
    services.AddScoped<ISynchronizationBackgroundService, SynchronizationBackgroundService>();
```

Would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: What does `lock my app` mean? What is the effect? I use the code you provided for testing, the thread executes normally without any problem. Do you have any error message?

Comment: You should be referring to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services/samples/6.0/BackgroundTasksSample) based on this document you can refer to.

Comment: i mean the app is frozen (swagger f.e.) when it execute the method from background task...

or maybe i should not just test it on debug mode ;D ?

Comment: Did you register the service in `IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`? I found that the background task is also executing when registering the service directly and my app works fine.